# How to disable all unselected cells in a UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to disable all of the cells within a UITableView that aren't being used? Within my application a user chooses a max of two cells and after two cells are selected I want all other cells to be disabled but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to disable the rows, you want to prevent the user from selecting additional rows, right?

Implement the `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. If there are already two rows selected you should return `nil`, otherwise return the index path.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (/* check if there are already two selected rows */) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return indexPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great but do you know why when I press and hold on another cell a checkmark shows up like your able to select it but when you let off it goes away?

Comment: Double check to see if the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is called in that case. You may need to add some logic to that method to ignore the selection if there are already two selections.

Comment: That method was implemented but I took it out to check if that was the case but the issue of the long hold still persists.

Comment: You must have some code that adds/removes the checkmark. Update that code as needed.